# SQL: Is [ID] a nessesity when using a stored proc

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Sorry for crappy title..

I have a stored proc(p_1) that returns values: OPEN or CLOSED,

Now what I want to do is write another stored proc(p_2) that looks into my database (audit.dbo) at a column targetDate and if p_1 is open and over the Target date (audit.dbo) then it should return 'Overdue' or 'On Time'

Now my question is should I match Audit_ID with stored proc(p_1)'s Audit_ID to see whether its over due or not. My Stored proc result is:

> AUD_ID: 1    Q1:10    Q2:30    Q3:40    Total:80    Status: Open

And my database table (audit.dbo) data is something like

> AUD_ID:1    Start_date:2013/12/03    Target_date: 2014/01/24

**My Proc Definition**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_GetSocre] 
AS 
BEGIN 
 SET NOCOUNT ON; 

   CREATE TABLE #tmp1( AUD_ID BIGINT, RowCounter BIGINT, DistinctCounter BIGINT
                    , NACounter BIGINT, Total BIGINT, [Status] VARCHAR(MAX) ) 

  INSERT INTO #tmp1 EXEC [p_GetCompleteIncompleteNaOverviewSCORE] 

  SELECT [Status] AS [Open/Closed], COUNT(*) AS [Status] 
  FROM #tmp1 
  GROUP BY [Status] 
END
```

Comment: can you show `Proc_1's Definition` ??

Comment: ok cool, but will it check if audit.dbo AUD_ID target date is the same AUD_ID from my proc and then i can check of its overdue or not?

Comment: More information on table definition and stored procedure will allow us to give you a better answer ...

Comment: Stored Proc: `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON GO ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_GetSocre] AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; CREATE TABLE #tmp1 ( AUD_ID BIGINT, RowCounter BIGINT, DistinctCounter BIGINT, NACounter BIGINT, Total BIGINT, [Status] VARCHAR(MAX) ) INSERT INTO #tmp1 EXEC [p_GetCompleteIncompleteNaOverviewSCORE] SELECT * FROM #tmp1 GROUP BY [Status] END`

Comment: @inzefinite any code you should add to your answer not in comments, its really hard to read code in comments section :)

Comment: yeah figured that now..Sorry

Comment: I do not see a question here.  Go ahead and join the temp table to the original table if that is the business logic.  I am assuming you are all set ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot more to your procedures (Dont know anything about the `p_GetCompleteIncompleteNaOverviewSCORE`) but I am guessing on the Table names and columns and some other information shown in your question. atleast you will have some idea how to go about doing this,

*Please check if you have a table called `audit.dbo` or `dbo.audit`* --<-- Warrning

Try something like this....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_Target_Status] 
AS 
BEGIN 
 SET NOCOUNT ON; 

   IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp1') IS NOT NULL  --<-- check for table Existance 
    DROP TABLE #tmp1                         -- if exist then drop 

   CREATE TABLE #tmp1( AUD_ID BIGINT, RowCounter BIGINT, DistinctCounter BIGINT
                    , NACounter BIGINT, Total BIGINT, [Status] VARCHAR(MAX) ) 

  INSERT INTO #tmp1 EXEC [p_GetCompleteIncompleteNaOverviewSCORE] 

 SELECT t2.AU_ID ,  CASE WHEN CAST(t2.TargetDate AS DATE) > CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
                        THEN 'Over Due' 
                        ELSE 'On Time' END AS [Target Status]

 FROM #tmp1 t1 INNER JOIN dbo.Audit t2
 ON t1.AUD_ID = t2.AUD_ID
 WHERE [Status] = 'Open'
END
```

Comment: How would you `Count(*)` this statement. I was trying something like: `SELECT t2.AUD_TargetDate,COUNT(*) CASE WHEN CAST(t2.AUD_TargetDate AS DATETIME) > CAST(GETDATE() AS DATETIME)`

Answer (score 0):

**You can not join the results from a stored procedure to a table directly.**

Either do one of the following.

1 -  Save the results to a table.  MY_TABLE has the same schema as the output from stored procedure MY_STORED_PROC

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE EXEC MY_STORED_PROC
```

2 - Change the stored procedure to a Table Valued Function.  Join the results to the static table.

CROSS APPLY example of TVF call.

http://craftydba.com/?p=3767

MULTI LINE TVF - Probably slower than in-line TVF.  Depends on your logic.

http://craftydba.com/?p=3754

Comment: Option three insert sproc into a #table or @table and join to that in your query.(not saying this is the best or worst option just that it's another option)

Comment: Just remember Zane, #table are only valid for the current SPID.  I like physical staging tables more since you do not have to worry about tempdb contention with other internal processes.  Also, you can pre-allocate the size.

Comment: True. However this is an option if this is all just in one query.